# ruby iterate and delete after grouping

Tags: ruby

I have a simple array:

```
[
    [0] {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 1
    },
    [1] {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 1
    },
    [2] {
        "user_id" => 1,
           "type" => 1
    },
    [3] {
        "user_id" => 2,
           "type" => 65
    },
    [4] {
        "user_id" => 1,
           "type" => 23
    },
    [5] {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 4
    }
]
```

All i want to do is remove elements that have the same user_id and type and then combine them together and put them back in as array. So the result would be in this case:

```
[
    [0] {
        "user_id" => 1,
           "type" => 1
    },
    [1] {
        "user_id" => 2,
           "type" => 65
    },
    [2] {
        "user_id" => 1,
           "type" => 23
    },
    [3] {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 4
    },
    [4] [
        [0] {
            "user_id" => 4,
               "type" => 1
        },
        [1] {
            "user_id" => 4,
               "type" => 1
        }
    ]
]
```

Is there an easy way of doing this or do I have to manually iterate through and do it? Thanks

Comment: That's not a valid ruby array

Comment: Sergio, it happens in a lot of questions and I don't even know how people generate those invalid arrays. Is it a special method or something?

Comment: @tokland: I believe it's output of some pretty printer.

Comment: @tokland https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

Comment: I think the output is from `PRY` tool.. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's not ruby, it's output of awesome_print gem

Comment: The format surprised me, too.  I think questions would be better, usually, using p or pp (pretty-print) format, because that output is valid Ruby code.  That makes it much easier for people to tinker with the data in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'pp'
a = [
     {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 1
    },
     {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 1
    },
     {
        "user_id" => 1,
           "type" => 1
    },
    {
        "user_id" => 2,
           "type" => 65
    },
    {
        "user_id" => 1,
           "type" => 23
    },
    {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 4
    }
]

pp a.group_by{|i| i.values_at("user_id","type") }.values

output:

[[{"user_id"=>4, "type"=>1}, {"user_id"=>4, "type"=>1}],
 [{"user_id"=>1, "type"=>1}],
 [{"user_id"=>2, "type"=>65}],
 [{"user_id"=>1, "type"=>23}],
 [{"user_id"=>4, "type"=>4}]]
```

**UPDATE**

```
require 'pp'
a = [
     {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 1
    },
     {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 1
    },
     {
        "user_id" => 1,
           "type" => 1
    },
    {
        "user_id" => 2,
           "type" => 65
    },
    {
        "user_id" => 1,
           "type" => 23
    },
    {
        "user_id" => 4,
           "type" => 4
    }
]

arr = a.map do |i|
  tot = a.count(i)
  next ([i] * tot) if tot > 1 ; i
end.uniq
pp arr
```

***Output:***

```
[[{"user_id"=>4, "type"=>1}, {"user_id"=>4, "type"=>1}],
 {"user_id"=>1, "type"=>1},
 {"user_id"=>2, "type"=>65},
 {"user_id"=>1, "type"=>23},
 {"user_id"=>4, "type"=>4}]
```

Comment: A very elegant solution